# Ogre3D trying to compile Tutorial Framework and keep getting an error. Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ogre3d

I recently set up Ogre3D and to make sure I did everything right I tried to compile the tutorial framework. Except every time I do I get this error:

> OGRE EXCEPTION(5:FileNotFoundException): 'resources_d.cfg' file not
>   found! in ConfigFile::load at
>   ..........\OgreMain\src\OgreConfigFile.cpp (line 88)

I'm using Code::Blocks and I did follow the instructions on the site to the letter. I also have copied the resources_d.cfg from the Ogre3D SDK into the *../Debug/bin/* folder next to the EXE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you did everything right from a design-time perspective, but you probably did not take the runtime side of things into account.

If you are trying to run your application directly from within Code::Blocks (or most IDEs for that matter) you will have to tell it from which working / execution directory. Usually you want it to be the one where your EXE is put in and where you also already copied the `resources_d.cfg` file to.

If think the menu path to correct the issue in Code::Blocks is:

```
Project -> Properties -> Build targets -> [name of target] -> Execution working dir
```